# How to make a Linux/Mac/Win installer CD?

Tags: installation, compact-disc, autorun, xulrunner

I developed a program with Xulrunner so it runs on those OS's but right now if you want to install it on Linux/Mac you need to manually copy the files and create shortcuts.

Is there a way to ease this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PackageMaker](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) on OS X.  For something both linux/Mac compatible, I guess you have to write a shell script to do the installing for you.

Answer (score 0):

For the Mac, if you can install the program just by dragging it into the Applications folder (for example), then by all means don't write an installer.

To make it easier, you might put the program into a disk image file (.dmg), perhaps with some nice background image that tells the user to drag the program to the Applications folder. Add a shortcut to the Applications folder as well.

Just look at some popular programs for examples.

Answer (score 0):

In general the Mac world despises installers. Mac users want to be able to copy a program whereever they want rather than click through an installer.

Linux users usually expect to compile a program from source or to use a package manager to install applications.